# OAuth2: Resource owner workflow

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

The python-social-auth is a fantastic library for integrating oauth2 backend with web application (in my case it is django).So now it is possible to login into my django app with social oauth2 services.

However, I'd like the application to act as a resource owner as well. An another application (such as a single page app) already having a token should be able to call into my django application (XHR Request). The django application in such a case should behave as a resource owner. It should use *introspect* (oauth2 token introspection) the token to validate the it and give access to its resource.

How can I customize python-social-auth (social-auth-app-django to be specific) to allow this workflow? The backend should be aware of the **token** in the request supplied, and should be able to skip login by supplying the token directly to a stage where we can fetch user data from token.

This can be achieved by doing the token validation in the application view and redirect to either social login or to resource view. However, my intention is to modify the social-auth pipeline to achieve this so that the *User* model implemented in social-auth can be effectively used to store user data to backend.

Comment: With `token` do you refer to a custom token built for your app, or are talking about OAuth2 client-side flow token provided by the service?

Comment: @omab This is access_token which can be passed as a bearer token to access a protected resource.

Comment: `access_token` based authentication is possible but not a built-in solution, you need to implement your own view that fits your project for it. Here's an [example](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token) for such functionality. From that view you can return anything that fits your project in order to ensure the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution came from [this graphene-django issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/249). As a solution, graphiql end point was served at "graphql" end point, whereas "api/graphql" end point can be accessed with a bearer token (obtained by a client for the user using password grant).

This solution uses rest-framework-social-oauth2 which is based on python-social-oauth, and django rest-framework library. It supports authentication based on social oauth providers, and adds access token (bearer) based access to the API end points.